# Remove folder in roaming using wix3.10 installer

Tags: wix, wix3.10

When uninstalling my application, I'd like to delete a folder that was added by the application.It seems like the uninstaller removes only the directories and files that were originally installed from the MSI file. How do I delete application created folder?

Comment: Can't you use the RemoveFolder nested in one component that will be uninstalled?

Comment: but how can we use that removefolder ?

Comment: I was unsure if you were asking if it was possible or how you could achieve it. I've added an answer, let me know if it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions on this [link](https://www.hass.de/content/wix-how-use-removefolderex-your-xml-scripts):

1. use WixUtil extensions:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
        xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
        >
   ```
2. then read the Folder path previously stored in the registry:

   ```
   <Property Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
        <RegistrySearch Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.SkuName)" Root="HKLM" Type="raw" Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER_REGSEARCH" Name="Path" />
   </Property>
   ```
3. Make sure the following component is included in you installer scripts:

   ```
   <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
       <Component Id="CleanupMainApplicationFolder" Guid="*">
            <RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.SkuName)" Name="Path" Type="string" Value="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes" />
            <!-- We need to use APPLICATIONFOLDER variable here or RemoveFolderEx
            will not remove on "install". -->
            <util:RemoveFolderEx On="uninstall" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" />
       </Component>
   </DirectoryRef>
   ```
4. Use the WiXUtil extension when you call both `candle` and `light`: `-ext WixUtilExtension`

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this is not working because I want to delete the folder in roaming that I created during runtime of an application.

Comment: OK. So can't you store that folder path in the registry when installing and then using it while uninstalling?

Comment: Mine was a question. your "is it possible?" is referred to storing the folder path in the registry? could you clarify?

Comment: yes, I can store that path in the registry. I had created my own folder in the registry where I can store the path that folder in the registry.

Comment: you can create a Registry Entry doing: `<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="enterGuid"> 
                <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyProduct">
                    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Version" Value="[ProductVersion]" KeyPath="yes"/>
                </RegistryKey>
            </Component>`